# Mapping the AZ to the selected subnet, and the subnets to the selected VPC

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a cloudformation template that creates some resources like EC2 instances. This template will be used in different AWS accounts. 
We have 3 accounts, one for test environment, one for dev environement, and one for production. In each account there are 2 VPCs (same region in all accounts).

My question, to properly architect the recources, when creating the EC2, we need to choose a VPC, a subnet inside the same VPC, and an availability zone of the same subnet. I need the Availability zone because I'm mounting the EFS in the userData of the instance, so that the instance can be connected to a mount target.

As known, there is an amount target in each subnet, and the dns changes according to the AZ. Here is what I put in the userData to mount the target:

```
echo "availability-zone.file-system-id.efs.aws-region.amazonaws.com:/ /efs-mount-point nfs4 nfsvers=4.1 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

I am not creating the instances directly, but I do through creating a launch configuration and an autoscaling group.

```
"Launchconfig":{
        "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
        "Properties":{
          "ImageId":{ "Fn::FindInMap":[ "AWSRegionToAMI", { "Ref":"AWS::Region" }, "AMIID" ] },
          "SecurityGroups":[ { "Ref":"EcsSecurityGroup" } ],
          "InstanceType": {"Ref":"InstanceType" },
          "IamInstanceProfile":{ "Ref":"EC2InstanceProfile" },
          "KeyName":{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "KeyPairMapping", {"Ref" : "EnvParam"}, "Key"] },
          "UserData":{  "Fn::Base64" : {
            "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
              "echo eu-west-1c.",{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "FileSystemMap", {"Ref" : "EnvParam"}, "FileSystemID"] },
              ".efs.",{ "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },".amazonaws.com:/ /efs-mount-target nfs defaults,vers=4.1 0 0",
              " >> /etc/fstab\n"
              ]]}
          }
        }
      },

      "AutoScalingGroup":{
        "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
        "Properties":{
          "VPCZoneIdentifier":{ "Ref":"SubnetID" },
          "LaunchConfigurationName":{ "Ref":"Launchconfig" },
          "MinSize":"1",
          "MaxSize":{ "Ref":"MaxSize" },
          "DesiredCapacity":{ "Ref":"DesiredCapacity" }
        }
      },
```

My question: **by using the mapping, how to get the value of the availablity zone in the userdata according to the chosen subnet ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished in two ways, depending on your use case:

1. The [`VPCZoneIdentifier`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-vpczoneidentifier) property for your [`AutoScalingGroup`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html) resource accepts a List of subnet-identifier strings. Alternatively, the [`AvailabilityZones`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-availabilityzones) property accepts a List of availability-zone strings. If you only specify a single Availability Zone / Subnet for your Auto Scaling Group, you can be sure that the instance will be launched within the specified Availability Zone.
2. If your Auto Scaling Group can launch instances in multiple Availability Zones, you can [Retrieve Instance Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) to determine the instance's current Availability Zone, e.g., by running the following command in a User-Data Script on the instance:

   ```
   AZ=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
   echo "$AZ.${FileSystemId}.efs.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com:/ /efs-mount-point nfs4 nfsvers=4.1 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
   ```

Comment: is it me or there is a forgotten `$` before `AZ` in the declaration ?

Comment: Shell variable assignment always takes the form `varname=value`, as defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_23).

Comment: Could you please check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270842/userdata-are-not-getting-executed-after-launching-the-instance-by-cloudformation) please thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get direct access to the user data during the creation of the stack.  But could you parameterize the value and reference the parameter in both places that you need it?