# userData are not getting executed after launching the instance by cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, user-data

I created a AWS cloudformation, which creates a launch configuration and an autoscaling group. In the user Data in the launch Config I have configured the file system mount target, and I installed the cloudwatch agent:

> **Code EDITED**

```
  "LaunchConfig":{
    "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
    "Metadata" : {
      "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
        "config" : {
          "files" : {
            "/etc/cwlogs.cfg": {
              "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "[general]",
                "state_file = /var/awslogs/state/agent-state",
                "[/var/log/syslog]",
                "file = /tmp/",
                "log_group_name = ecs-dataloader",
                "log_stream_name = ECS-loader",
                "datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S"
                ]]},
                "mode": "000755",
                "owner": "root",
                "group": "root"
            },
            "/etc/ecs/ecs.config": {
              "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "ECS_CLUSTER=", { "Ref" : "ClusterName" }
              ]]},
              "mode": "000755",
              "owner": "root",
              "group": "root"
            }
          },
          "commands": {
            "Update": {
              "command": "yum -y update"
            },
            "InstallNfs":{
              "command": "yum -y install nfs-utils"
            },
            "CreatFolder": {
              "command": "mkdir -p /efs-mount-point/"
            },
            "EditPerms": {
              "command": "chown ec2-user:ec2-user /efs-mount-point/"
            },
            "MountPoint": {
              "command": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "AZ=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)\n",
                "echo LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs / ext4 defaults,discard    0 0\n",
                "$AZ.",{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "FileSystemMap", {"Ref" : "EnvParam"}, "FileSystemID"] },
                ".efs.",{ "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },".amazonaws.com:/  /efs-script-import-tmp nfs4 nfsvers=4.1 0 0 >> /etc/fstab"
              ]]}
            },
            "Mount": {
              "command": "mount -a -t nfs4"
            },
            "CloudWatchAgent": {
              "command": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O\n",
                "python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region ",{"Ref" : "AWS::Region"},"\n",
                "chmod +x ./awslogs-agent-setup.py ./awslogs-agent-setup.py -n -r",
                {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}," -c /etc/cwlogs.cfg"
              ]]}
            }
          },
          "services" : {
            "sysvinit" : {
              "awslogs"  : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Properties":{
      "ImageId":{ "Fn::FindInMap":[ "AWSRegionToAMI", { "Ref":"AWS::Region" }, "AMIID" ] },
      "SecurityGroups":[ { "Ref":"EcsSecurityGroup" } ],
      "InstanceType": {"Ref":"InstanceType" },
      "IamInstanceProfile":{ "Ref":"EC2InstanceProfile" },
      "KeyName":{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "KeyPairMapping", {"Ref" : "EnvParam"}, "Key"] },
      "UserData":{  "Fn::Base64" : {
        "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
          "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
          "         --stack ", { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
          "         --resource LaunchConfig",
          "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },"\n"
        ]]}
      }
    }
  }
```

The image details :   `"eu-west-1": { "AMIID":"ami-ba346ec9" },`

After running the template, the resources got created successfuly. So I connected to my instance that got created by the autoscaling group via SSH to see if the userData was properly run and set.
Unfortunately, After checking, this is what I found in the /etc/fstab file:

```
   $ cat /etc/fstab
   LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs    /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0


   $ cat /etc/ecs/ecs.config
   cat: /etc/ecs/ecs.config: No such file or directory
```

The instance is not connected to the `file system`, the file that I tried to create in the `cloudformation::init` `/etc/cwlogs.cfg` does not exist either (it's the `cloudwatch agent` config file) . Can any one tell me what is wrong in the user data that it didn't get executed?

I tried to check the log files but :

```
$ cat /var/log/cfn-init.log 
cat: /var/log/cfn-init.log: No such file or directory
```

What is the problem here ?

> **EDIT**

```
$ cat /var/log/cloud-init-ouput.log
...

Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:final' at Fri, 17 Feb 2017 11:43:42 +0000. Up 44.66 seconds.
+ yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack Mystack --resource LaunchConfig --region eu-west-1
Loading "priorities" plugin
Loading "update-motd" plugin
Config time: 0.009
Command line error: no such option: --stack
Feb 17 11:43:43 cloud-init[2814]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
Feb 17 11:43:43 cloud-init[2814]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Feb 17 11:43:43 cloud-init[2814]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 finished at Fri, 17 Feb 2017 11:43:43 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 45.18 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I resolved the problem: I Update the cloud-init in the user data before calling the meta-data and instead of installing the cloudwatch agent in the metadata, I did in the userdata.

```
          "UserData":{  "Fn::Base64" : {
            "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
              "yum -y install aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
              "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v",
              "         --stack ", { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
              "         --resource LaunchConfig",
              "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },"\n",
              "# Get the CloudWatch Logs agent\n",
              "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py\n",
              "# Install the CloudWatch Logs agent\n",
              "python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py -n -r ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, " -c /etc/cwlogs.cfg || error_exit 'Failed to run CloudWatch Logs agent setup'\n",
              "service awslogs start"
          ]]}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem but works around it

Answer (score 5):

User Data log files are located at:

- Linux cloud-init: `/var/log/cloud-init.log`
- Windows EC2Config: `C:\cfn\log\cloud-init.log`

Check to see whether anything is in the log file. If not, then something's wrong with passing the User Data script from the template. (Why do you have the initial empty quotes in the Join?)

Comment: the initial empty quotes are the delimeter. it's empty as I don't need it in the user data script.

Comment: Just checked the `/var/log/cloud-init.log` could not find any thing from the user data in there.

Comment: Your UserData format [looks correct](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-general.html#scenario-one-pseudo-parameter). You'll need to do some testing to see why User Data isn't running. Try a simple version that just writes some text to `/tmp/test` file. Also @wjordan makes a point -- are you using a standard Amazon Linux AMI? It looks like you're using ubuntu instead.

Comment: With the new images from Linux 2 AMI, the /var/log/cloud-init.log exists. In my particular case i had some issues with the script.  You can run the script inside the lib instance folder. The content of the script is there and you can run it against the machine.

Comment: the user data script is inside `/var/lib/cloud/instance`

Answer (score 3):

`cfn-init` is only installed by default on Amazon Linux AMI, so if you're using any other Image ID to launch your EC2 instance you need to ensure that it's installed correctly before invoking it. See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41256625/2518355) to the question, "[Installing packages using apt-get in CloudFormation file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28101267/2518355)" for more info.

Comment: Nice find! It appears that User Data is [installed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) on Ubuntu cloud images, but not `cfn-init`.

Comment: I changed the AMI image to a Linux ECS optimized one, as I am creating a ECS cluster. I enhanced the template because I realized I was forgetting some important commands. but nothing has changed. I'm really going nuts here I have tried everything

Comment: I tried @wjordan solution, by keeping ubuntu image and adding the `cfn-init` installation; but still no good result. Simple other test, I checked if `nfs-utils` package is installed: `rpm -q nfs-utils
le paquet nfs-utils n'est pas installé`
it says it is not

Comment: I also tried adding accessKey and sercretKey to the userdata in `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init` but it does not work. I'm still trying .............;

Comment: @Somar judging from the line `+ yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack Mystack --resource LaunchConfig --region eu-west-1` in your `cloud-init-output.log` output, it seems you forgot to add a newline between `yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap` and the other command.

Comment: @wjordan Yes, I have solved the problem, see the answer below. I still have one problem though, can't install cloudwatch agent. I'll post a new question for that. Thanks

Comment: @wjordan Can you check Please [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300756/cant-install-cloudwatch-agent-by-cloudformation)