# Can't install cloudwatch agent by cloudformation on Amazon ECS-optimized AMI

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a cloudformation template, which creates some resources as EC2 instance, `autoscaling group` and `launchConfiguration`. 
By the `userData` property of the `launchConfiguration` resource, I tried to install the `Cloudwatch agent` as follows:

```
"UserData":{  "Fn::Base64" : {
            "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
              "yum -y install aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
              "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v",
              "         --stack ", { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
              "         --resource LaunchCongig",
              "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },"\n",
              "yum -y install wget\n",
              "# Get the CloudWatch Logs agent\n",
              "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py\n",
              "# Install the CloudWatch Logs agent\n",
              "python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py -n -r ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, " -c /etc/cwlogs.cfg || error_exit 'Failed to run CloudWatch Logs agent setup'\n",
              "service awslogs start"
            ]]}
```

After ssh into the instance, I checked the file `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to see if everything is fine, but here is what I got:

```
+ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py
--2017-02-17 14:36:10--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.216.226.59
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.226.59|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 47998 (47K) [text/x-python]
Saving to: ‘awslogs-agent-setup.py’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ......    100%  196K=0.2s

2017-02-17 14:36:10 (196 KB/s) - ‘awslogs-agent-setup.py’ saved [47998/47998]

+ python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py -n -r eu-west-1 -c /etc/cwlogs.cfg

Step 1 of 5: Installing pip ...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./awslogs-agent-setup.py", line 1144, in <module>
    main()
  File "./awslogs-agent-setup.py", line 1140, in main
    setup.setup_artifacts()
  File "./awslogs-agent-setup.py", line 693, in setup_artifacts
    self.install_pip()
  File "./awslogs-agent-setup.py", line 600, in install_pip
    fail("Could not install pip. Please try again or see " + AGENT_SETUP_LOG_FILE + " for more details")
TypeError: fail() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
+ error_exit 'Failed to run CloudWatch Logs agent setup'
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 8: error_exit: command not found
Feb 17 14:36:12 cloud-init[2798]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [127]
Feb 17 14:36:12 cloud-init[2798]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Feb 17 14:36:12 cloud-init[2798]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 finished at Fri, 17 Feb 2017 14:36:12 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 85.78 seconds
```

What is wrong with this script? Is there any other way to install the agent?
Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I figured out that is because maybe the `python-pip` package didn't get installed so I added this to the `userData`:

```
  "yum -y install python-pip\n",
```

After that I played the  template again and strangely I got the same Error.

I am usinh an `Amazon ECS-optimized AMI`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing the agent directly by `yum awslogs`:

```
      "UserData":{  "Fn::Base64" : {
        "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
          "yum -y install aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
          "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v",
          "         --stack ", { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
          "         --resource launchConfig",
          "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },"\n",
          "yum -y install awslogs\n",
          "service awslogs start"
        ]]}
```

Here is the output from the log file:

```
Installed:
  awslogs.noarch 0:1.1.2-1.10.amzn1                                             

Dependency Installed:
  aws-cli.noarch 0:1.11.29-1.45.amzn1                                           
  aws-cli-plugin-cloudwatch-logs.noarch 0:1.3.3-1.15.amzn1                      
  freetype.x86_64 0:2.3.11-15.14.amzn1                                          
  libjpeg-turbo.x86_64 0:1.2.90-5.14.amzn1                                      
  mailcap.noarch 0:2.1.31-2.7.amzn1                                             
  python27-botocore.noarch 0:1.4.86-1.62.amzn1                                  
  python27-colorama.noarch 0:0.2.5-1.7.amzn1                                    
  python27-dateutil.noarch 0:2.1-1.3.amzn1                                      
  python27-docutils.noarch 0:0.11-1.15.amzn1                                    
  python27-futures.noarch 0:3.0.3-1.3.amzn1                                     
  python27-imaging.x86_64 0:1.1.6-19.9.amzn1                                    
  python27-jmespath.noarch 0:0.9.0-1.11.amzn1                                   
  python27-ply.noarch 0:3.4-3.12.amzn1                                          
  python27-pyasn1.noarch 0:0.1.7-2.9.amzn1                                      
  python27-rsa.noarch 0:3.4.1-1.8.amzn1                                         

Complete!
+ service awslogs start
Starting awslogs: [  OK  ]
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 finished at Fri, 17 Feb 2017 15:33:42 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 83.47 seconds
```

Everything works fine this way. Hope that will help someone someday!

Answer (score 2):

For ECS specifically, see [Using CloudWatch Logs with Container Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html) in the EC2 Container Service documentation for details on configuring CloudWatch Logs. The documentation recommends using `yum install -y awslogs` instead of the Python install script.

The documentation provides a complete sample in the [Configuring CloudWatch Logs at Launch with User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html#cwlogs_user_data) section.

In your case, since you're already managing your config files using `cfn-init` and `CloudFormation::Init` metadata in CloudFormation, you don't need any complex parsing of config files in your User-Data script, but you can still use the script as a reference. One thing worth adding to your User-Data script is running `chkconfig awslogs on` to make sure the service continues running on the instance after a reboot.

Comment: in the CloudFormation::Init; I did it this way : 
`{ "Ref" : "ClusterName" },"/",{"Ref" : "ContainerInstances"}` I didn't test yet but is that the same as doing it by userData ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to put this script above in UserData?

Comment: Since you're using CloudFormation, I think using `CloudFormation::Init` to reference those fields is probably a better choice and easier to manage. This example from the documentation is meant for configuring entirely from user-data alone, if you're launching the instance directly from the console for example. I'd stick to what you have already and just use the details in the documentation as a reference to compare against - perhaps add the `chkconfig awslogs on` to make sure the service always starts even after a reboot of the instance.

Comment: in fact,  doing this in `CloudFormation::Init` didn't work it gave me a dependancy error beacuse I am calling the containerInsatances inside it itself

Comment: Here the container is the launchConfiguration, where we set the `Cloudformation::Init`. what do you think please.

Comment: If you have further questions unrelated to your question regarding installing the CloudWatch agent on ECS, post a separate question with relevant details.